# Nginx restart command failing after installing passenger

Tags: nginx, passenger, ubuntu-8.04

I just installed passenger for nginx on my Ubuntu (8.04) box. Now "sudo /etc/init.d/nginx restart" fails with the following errors:

```
Restarting nginx: [emerg]: bind() to 0.0.0.0:3000 failed (98: Address already in use)
[emerg]: bind() to 0.0.0.0:3000 failed (98: Address already in use)
[emerg]: bind() to 0.0.0.0:3000 failed (98: Address already in use)
[emerg]: bind() to 0.0.0.0:3000 failed (98: Address already in use)
[emerg]: bind() to 0.0.0.0:3000 failed (98: Address already in use)
[emerg]: still could not bind()
nginx.
```

I updated the ..init.d/nginx config to point to /opt/nginx after installing passenger, so that should all be fine.

If I kill the process with "sudo killall nginx" and try to start nginx, it works fine, but restart doesn't work.

Comment: Seems like port 3000 is being used by some other service.  You can do "ps auxwww|grep LISTEN|grep 3000"
to see what process is using the port.

Answer (score 1):

Just ignore

```
nginx: [warn] conflicting server name "69.162.95.11" on 69.162.95.11:80, ignored
```

It's not error just warning about 69.162.95.11 is not shared IP
About

```
nginx: [emerg] bind() to 69.162.95.14:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
```

just restart Nginx will solve this issue if not then check none ssl port under tweak settings. The none ssl port should be 8081 after install.
maestro
02-12-2011, 01:42 AM
turn off port 80 from apache or ltespeed
and turn on nginxcp as port 80

Answer (score 1):

In my case it was that apache was already installed and it was using the port; so i just did:

```
killall -9 apache2
```

Maybe in your case is another software, you can use this command to check what ports are listening petitions

```
netstat -a | egrep 'Proto|LISTEN'
```